# Как перетащить кнопку в java?

Tags: java, swing, button, drag-n-drop

Нужно перетащить кнопку при зажатом ctrl.
Пишу вот такой код, кнопка перемещается c морганием и двойственностью(т.е появляется в некий момент такая же кнопка, но в другом месте), и мышка уходит далеко вперед кнопки, а кнопка как бы за ней перемещается. Не могу понять в чем ошибка, на многих сайтах пишут, что когда перемещаешь кнопку надо отнимать от предыдущих ее координат текущие, но тогда если, я так пишу вообще не перемещается.

```
public class Mouse extends JFrame{
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton button1;
    private JPanel showPanel;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private static int xPosition,lastX;
    private static int yPosition,lastY;
    private static boolean flag=false,flag1=false;



    public Mouse(){
        super("Mouse Application");
        setLocation(450,145);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        showPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                button1.setLocation(e.getX(),e.getY());
                repaint();
            }
        });


        showPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseMoved(e);
                xPosition=e.getX();
                yPosition=e.getY();
                textField1.setText("x: "+xPosition+" y: "+yPosition);
                repaint();
            }
        });


        setVisible(true);


        button1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyPressed(e);
                flag=e.isControlDown();
            }
        });
        button1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mousePressed(e);
                if(flag) {
                    flag1 = true;
                    lastX=e.getX();
                    lastY=e.getY();
                }
            }
        });

        button1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseReleased(e);
                flag=false;
                flag1=false;
            }
        });
        /*button1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseDragged(e);
                if(flag1){
                    button1.setLocation(lastX-e.getX(),lastY-e.getY());
                    lastX=e.getX();
                    lastY=e.getY();
                }
            }
        });*/

        button1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseDragged(e);
                if(flag1){
                    button1.setLocation(e.getX(),e.getY());
                    //lastX=e.getX();
                    //lastY=e.getY();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Mouse();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Координаты в `MouseEvent` даются в системе компонента, для которого создано событие ( т.е. при перетаскивании (0, 0) - левый верхний угол кнопки). Нужно посчитать смещение мыши относительно точки нажатия и сдвинуть кнопку на это смещение. После этого точка нажатия снова окажется под курсором.

Можно заменить ваши слушатели мыши для кнопки вот на такой адаптер:

```
MouseAdapter mouseDrag = new MouseAdapter() {
    // запоминаем координаты нажатия в адаптере
    int clickX, clickY;
    // сюда же можно перенести flag1

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // вместо KeyListener можно проверить нажатие CTRL, ALT или SHIFT прямо тут
        if ( (e.getModifiersEx() & InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) != 0 ) {
            flag1 = true;
            clickX=e.getX();
            clickY=e.getY();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        flag1=false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if(flag1){
            // сдвиг мыши относительно точки нажатия
            int dx = e.getX() - clickX;
            int dy = e.getY() - clickY;

            // после перемещения курсор окажется над той же точкой кнопки,
            // в которой был до сдвига мыши
            button1.setLocation( button1.getX() + dx, button1.getY() + dy );

            // repaint не нужен, setLocation его сам вызывает
        }
    }
};

button1.addMouseListener( mouseDrag );
button1.addMouseMotionListener( mouseDrag );
```